# Tables from single database automatically copied to other databases upon creation - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I had a single database in my PostgreSQL which had 6 tables in the public schema. I dropped the database so that my server had no databases. I then started creating new databases and i realized that every time i create a new db, the 6 tables with their data from the deleted databases are in the public schema of the created db.

Are the tables stored somewhere in the postgres server and get copied upon creation of new databases? If so how can i stop this from happening? How can i permanently delete these 6 tables?

I would really appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new database, the new one is a copy of [the template1 database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

If every new database you create contains those tables, you probably created those tables in the `template1` database.

You need to connect to the `template1` database and drop those 6 tables there.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!